# Select de 3 tablas diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

tengo una pregunta, necesito hacer un select de tres tablas diferentes mostrando el mismo campo pero con diferentes nombres segun lo que sea. Os adjunto codigo para poder expresar mejor la pregunta

```
create table Persona(
DNI         char(9),
nome        varchar(30)     not null,
enderezo    varchar(100)    not null,
telefono    char(9)         not null,
empleado    bit             not null,
cliente     bit             not null,
propietario bit             not null,
nss         char(11)        null,

Constraint PK_persona Primary key (DNI)
);

go

create table Sucursal(  
cod_sucursal    char(4),
enderezo        varchar(100)    not null,
telefono        char(9)         not null,

Constraint PK_Sucursal Primary key (cod_sucursal)

);

go

create table Propiedad(
cod_propiedad   char(4),
enderezo        varchar(100)    not null,
m2              int             not null,
num_cuartos     tinyint         not null,
num_baños       tinyint         not null,
tipo            char(1)         not null,
data_alta       date            not null,
info_vexetacion varchar(200)    null,
cortes          bit             null,
terraza         bit             null,
distancia_playa int             null,
vistas_mar      bit             null,
cod_sucursal    char(4)         null,
DNI             char(9)         not null,

Constraint PK_Propiedade Primary key (cod_propiedad),

Constraint FK_Propiedad_Sucursal Foreign key (cod_sucursal) references Sucursal(cod_sucursal)
    on update cascade on delete set null,
Constraint FK_Propiedad_Propietario Foreign key (DNI) references Persona (DNI)
);

go

create table Prezo_prop(
cod_propiedad       char(4),
data_ini            date,
data_fin            date        null,
prezo               money       not null,

Constraint PK_Prezo Primary key (cod_propiedad,data_ini),
Constraint FK_Propiedad_Prezo Foreign key (cod_propiedad) references Propiedad (cod_propiedad)
);
go


create table Actividades(
cod_actividad       char(4),
nome                varchar(20)     not null,
duracion            tinyint         not null,
nivel               tinyint         not null,
cod_propiedad       char(4)         not null,

Constraint PK_Actividades Primary key (cod_actividad),
Constraint FK_Actividades_Propiedad Foreign key (cod_propiedad) references Propiedad (cod_propiedad),
);

go

create table Aluga(
DNI             char(9),
cod_propiedad   char(4),
data_com        date        not null,
data_fin        date        not null,

Constraint PK_Aluga Primary key (DNI,cod_propiedad),
Constraint FK_Aluga_Cliente Foreign key (DNI) references Persona (DNI),
Constraint FK_Aluga_Propiedad Foreign key (cod_propiedad) references Propiedad (cod_propiedad)

); 
go

create table Dirixe(
cod_sucursal    char(4),
DNI             char(9),
data_alta       date,
data_baixa      date        null,

Constraint PK_Dirixe Primary key (cod_sucursal,DNI,data_alta),
Constraint FK_Dirixe_Cliente Foreign key (DNI) references Persona (DNI),
Constraint FK_Dirixe_Sucursal Foreign key (cod_sucursal) references Sucursal (cod_sucursal)
);

go

create table Traballa(
cod_sucursal    char(4),
DNI             char(9),
data_alta       date,
data_baixa      date        null,

Constraint PK_Traballa Primary key (cod_sucursal,DNI,data_alta),
Constraint FK_Traballa_Cliente Foreign key (DNI) references Persona (DNI),
Constraint FK_Traballa_Sucursal Foreign key (cod_sucursal) references Sucursal (cod_sucursal)

);

go
```

la cuestion es que necesito saber el codigo de la propiedad y el que la alquilo y a la vez tambien el nombre del propietario. Al ser los dos campos nombre probé con varias sentencias y la que mas se ajusta a lo que me piden es la siguiente

```
select P.cod_propiedad,P.enderezo, nome as propietario
from Propiedad P
inner join Aluga
on P.data_alta=aluga.data_com
inner join Persona
on Persona.DNI=Aluga.DNI

union

select P.cod_propiedad,P.enderezo, nome as arrendatario
from Propiedad P
inner join Aluga
on P.data_alta=aluga.data_com
inner join Persona
on Persona.DNI=P.DNI
```

pero me da dos filas con los nombres de los propietarios y el que lo alquilo pero con el mismo nombre de columna. Como puedo hacer para que en la misma fila muestre dos columnas diferentes con estos nombres.
Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando `alias` puedes hacer más de un `inner join` a una tabla con distintas condiciones, y llamar a los datos desde ese `alias`.

Ejemplo:

```
select P.cod_propiedad,P.enderezo, 
P1.nome as propietario, P2.nome as arrendatario
from Propiedad P
inner join Aluga A on P.data_alta=A.data_com
inner join Persona P1 on P1.DNI=A.DNI
inner join Persona P2 on P2.DNI=P.DNI
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes es por que la funcion union une dos tablas del mismo tañaño, agregando las filas de ambas en una nueva tabla.

La solucion a tu Query la encontramos en las sentencias JOIN, estas se encargan de unir dos tablas por medio de campos en comun, como lo son las PK de una y la FK de otra, pero en ves de sumar filas, estas se agregan en forma de campos. Ahora que si hay dos campos que traeremos de la misma tabla pero con llaves diferentes debemos agregar un nombre alternativo para que el sistema pueda diferenciarlo.

Por lo que tu query quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT
Propiedad.cod_propiedad,
Propiedad.enderezo, 
Propietario.nome AS propietario,
Arrendatario.nome AS arrendatario
    FROM Propiedad Propiedad
    INNER JOIN Aluga
        ON Propiedad.data_alta = Aluga.data_com
    INNER JOIN Persona Propietario
        ON Propietario.DNI = Aluga.DNI
    INNER JOIN Persona Arrendatario
        ON Arrendatario.DNI = Propiedad.DNI
```

Como puedes ver usamos la primera tabla de la siguiente forma

```
INNER JOIN Persona Propietario
```

*Donde despues de la sentencia de relacion agregamos el nombre de la tabla y un alias **Propietario***

posteriormente llamamos de nuevo la tabla para otro campo con:

```
INNER JOIN Persona Arrendatario
```

*Usando la misma estructura: sentencia de relación, nombre de la tabla y alias **Arrendatario***

De esta forma el sistema usa en memoria dos tablas y las diferencia correctamente para el result que buscamos.

Más información sobre INNER JOIN: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Más información sobre Alias: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp